# Two if statements, only one works

Tags: java, android

I have two `if` statements in my code, but when both are `true`, it only only makes the second `if`. How should I write it?

```
String s1 = editTextl.getText().toString();
double d = 0;

if (s1.contains("H")) {
    d = + H;     //H is double with value of 1
}
if (s1.contains("O")) {
    d = + O;     //O is double with value of 16   
}

TextView.setText(" " + getString(R.string.vysledek) + " " + d);
```

When I type HO in EditText, TextView should return value of 17, but it returns only 16. Why?

Comment: You wouldve known that both ifs were hit (and not that one was skipped, as you assumed), had you put some sysouts in your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to write it as follows, replacing `= +` with `+=`:

```
if (s1.contains("H")) {
    d += H;
}

if (s1.contains("O")) {
   d += O;
}
```

**`+=`** is a so-called **compound assignment operator**. It adds the right operand to the left operand.

The inverse, **`=+`**, just assigns the right operand to the left operand and is equivalent to a simple assignment using **`=`**. The unary **`+`** operator is ignored.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `= +` with `+=`.

`=` is an assignment operator, `+` is an unary plus operator that basically does nothing. So you're assigning a new value to the variable.

`+=` is "add to the current value of left hand side".

Answer (score 1):

```
    double d = 0;

    if (s1.contains("H")) {

        d += 1; // H is double with value of 1

    }

    if (s1.contains("O")) {

        d += 16; // O is double with value of 16

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `= +` assignments to `+=` assignments - `d = + H` is really just interpreted by the compiler as `d = +H`. You're not actually adding `H` to `d`, you're just setting `d = H`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `d = + H` with   `d += H` and `d = + O` with `d += O`